# ASP 0146 New session Failed Error on ASP pages - IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5

We have many websites running on our IIS servers, we host both asp and asp.net sites. They used to work ok but from last few days we are seeing errors on asp pages and the requests fails with error - HTTP/1.1 New Session Failed. They work ok when i tried restarting IIS but now this also doesn't seem to work. I enabled tracing and i see ASP 1046 New session failed error in the log file. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue with asp pages and not aspx pages under same site?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/4734/new-session-failed

Comment: can you show error from EventLog?